# How can I run a batch of commands inside one "screen" window?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

I'm using screen (LINUX) to run servers or task, but I want to put more than one task in one screen, is it impossible? Like:

```
screen -A -m -d -S test_screen userdel -r user_test && useradd -m -p 'encrypt_pass' user_test
```

How to change && because it leads first task left in screen and another execute in display and "" doesn't help, too.

I want to do it that each task executes one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `screen -A -m -d -S test_screen sh -c "userdel -r user_test && useradd -m -p 'encrypt_pass' user_test"`

Encasing the command in `sh -c ""` runs the whole command in the default shell

Answer (score 0):

Put all commands you want to execute into a shell script and run it with `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas:

1. Put the commands in a script, run the script from within the `screen`.
2. Use subshell (i.e. put the commands inside `( )`  )
3. Use `bash -c 'command a && command b'` as the command to be run by `screen`